# How do I "install the modules with `npm install` and run `node index."

Tags: npm-install

I stumbled upon a very desirable tool with some quite esoteric instructions.

This is what I would like to make use of:

https://github.com/MehediH/Bulksplash?ref=producthunt

[BulkSplash Folder Contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnMlq.png)

I apologise but I must ask for an absolute beginner's explanation - I've been searching for quite some time on how to begin to use a tool like this but the explanations are far too technical.

The only instructions in the readme are "install the modules with `npm  install` and run `node index`."

Where do I even begin?

Thank you very much for reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you must make sure that you have Node.js installed because you need it to run JavaScript outside of browser.

NPM is a Node Package Manager, as it's name says it helps you to manage packages built for that platform, allowing you to easy download, use and keep up-to-date those packages.

Guide on how everything works is already written on [npm official site](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/what-is-npm),
if you follow this link you will find that guide, on first glance it is quite long, but considering your needs you can skip a lot of points.

Just make sure to read everything from 1-10th point of Getting started, there is everything you need to be able to use node.js for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the nudge in the right direction - I'm happily using Bulksplash less than an hour later!

Install this: https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Windows + R, enter CMD and run to open the command line

entering node -v into the command line products output "v8.9.4"

entering npm -v produces "5.6.0" (All is going well.)

put the Bulksplash folder in your user folder C:/Users/Yournamehere, rename bulksplash folder Bulk

enter cd Bulk into command line

enter install npm package

check to see if node_modules folder was added to Bulk folder

receive an error when entering node index into the command line

Error: Cannot find module Request

enter npm install progress

enter node index

Error: Cannot find module Commander

npm install Commander

enter node index

Error: Cannot find module Progress

npm install Progress

node index

Welcome to Bulksplash!

Damn it feels good working this stuff out :)

Entering node index --amount 100 downloads 100 random free images!

Awesome!